# J2EE and external URL handlers, having doubts about design

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am developing a J2EE application on Glassfish 3.1 which will use one external library that relies heavily on URLs. The URLs will use a custom protocol (e.g. `db:123` where `123` is ID of a record in a database). I am having doubts on how to implement the URL protocol handler (and its `URLConnection` implementation), because this protocol handler will use EJBs to fetch data from the database.

The `db` protocol handler needs to be registered globally at the moment of JVM startup through `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs` flag. (I couldn't find a better way to do this in Glassfish.) Anyway, because it is registered at JVM startup, it has no knowledge of any EJBs that that it may call at the moment of opening URL streams. So what I did is create a singleton registry class to which database handlers can be registered. This registry is used by `URLConnection` whenever a stream is requested (it will search the registry for a database handler and use it to fetch data).

Then, an EJB will register itself as database handler in a `@PostConstruct` method. This way, any time a `db:XXX` URL is used, EJBs will be called indirectly to fetch the data.

Somehow I feel that this design is a bit dirty, but I'm very limited because of custom URL handlers. If you have any suggestions or tips that you can give me, that would be great.

Comment: I don't have the experience to answer this... but it is a good question.